# Path independent line integral and potential function?

Tags: calculus, integration, partial-derivative

How to calculate:

$\int_S \frac{(x - y)}{x(x+y)}dx + \frac{(y - x)}{y(x+y)}dy$

for the curve S: $y = 2sin(\pi x) $ from ${ (\frac{1}{6} , 1)}$ to ${ (\frac{5}{6} , 1})$.

I set $P=\frac{x - y}{x(x+y)}$ and $Q=\frac{y-x}{y(x+y)}$, but struggle with their partial derivatives. Will they be $P_y=Q_x=-\frac{2}{(x+y)^2}$ for all $(x, y)\in D$? Can anyone help with the partial derivate?

If I can prove that, then there is a scalar function $\phi$ such that $F=(P, Q)=\nabla\phi$. How would this potential function look like?

After finding $\phi$, the line integral (path independent) becomes
$$\int_S \frac{(x - y)}{x(x+y)}dx + \frac{(y - x)}{y(x+y)}dy=\phi(\frac{5}{6}, 1)-\phi(\frac{1}{6}, 1).$$ Is that correct?

Comment: I use the quotient rule but end up with a very heavy calculation which I assume is wrong, so would need help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiate $$P=\frac{x - y}{x(x+y)}$$ with respect to $y$ implies $$P_y=\frac {-2}{(x+y)^2}$$

Differentiate $$Q=\frac{y-x }{y(x+y)}$$ with respect to $x$ implies $$Q_x=\frac {-2}{(x+y)^2}$$ Therefore $P_y=Q_x.$ Integrating $P $ with respect to $x$ we get $$ \Phi(x,y)=2ln(x+y)-ln(x)+g(y)$$ Since $\Phi _y=Q$, we find $g'(y)=-\frac {1}{y}$ thus $g(y)=-ln(y).$ We have found $$\Phi (x,y) =   
2ln(x+y)-ln(x)-ln(y)$$Therefore $$\int_S \frac{(x - y)}{x(x+y)}dx + \frac{(y - x)}{y(x+y)}dy=\phi(\frac{5}{6}, 1)-\phi(\frac{1}{6}, 1)=ln(121/245).$$

Comment: Nice one. Can you please explain the differentiation from P to Py even more detailed?

Comment: This is a partial derivative approach. You consider x as a constant and use the quotient rule to get $P_y$.

Comment: Not sure if I can solve it. Is it possible to show for P?

Answer (score 0):

The potential function $\phi(x,y)=ln{(x+y)^{2}\over xy}$ induces the electrical field as described in question(Take gradient and check it out!)

Comment: This is for my level still a bit to difficult. Can you please explain even more?

Comment: Sure! Now writing a complementary answer...

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't require any electromagnetic information at all! It's all up to mathematics. Suppose you wanna solve $\int{E.dl}$ in which $E$ and $dl$ are both vectors and '.' between them implies on inner product. Now let $E$ and $dl$ be $(E_{1},E_{2},...,E_{n})$ and $(dx_{1},dx_{2},...,dx_{n})$ then the corresponding inner product gives us $E.dl=E_{1}dx_1+E_{2}dx_2+...+E_{n}dx_n$ which is summation over all component by component multiplications. Now suppose $E$ depends on variables $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ and so is a function $\phi(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. This function has this property that its partial differentiation respect to each of $x_1,x_2,...,x_n$ results in each of $E_{1},E_{2},...,E_{n}$ bijectively, meanwhile ${{\partial\phi}\over {\partial x_i}}=E_i$. This means E is so called "Gradient" of function $\phi(x_1,x_2,...,x_n)$. In this case, the predefined integral can be reformulated as $\int{E.dl}=\int{\nabla\phi.dl=\int d\phi}$ according to mathematical rules. Bounding integral is also likewise.

Comment: Not sure if I am unclear but the task doesn't involve any information about electromagnetism :) My problem is about the partial differentiation and to find the potential function.

Comment: Yes...I just tried to state some electromagnetic intuition....sorry if i confused you but this problem has a very clear mathematical approach. I think that the another answer also mentioned by Mr. Riazi Kermani is even more helpful...

Comment: Yes, his answer is very helpful but I would need help with the differentiation from P to Py. Are you able to present the steps more detailed?

Comment: actually if you wanna differentiate an n-variable function respect to one of its variables you must consider the other variables as constant and do the ordinary derivation. For example let us differentiate f(x,y)=x*sin(y)+y*exp(x). With respect to y, the derivation is x*cos(y)+exp(x) and with respect to x it is sin(y)+y*exp(x)